# TFS Build Issues With Multiple Versions of the Same Assembly in Different Projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, tfsbuild

I keep running into an issue with our TFS build server.  I've got 2 projects (both in the same solution), 1 is a WebForms project, running .Net 4.0.  The second is an ASP .Net MVC5 project running .Net 4.5.  There is also a Silverlight project, but the problem is reproducible with just the first two.

Both of these projects use NuGet packages for various libraries.  Sometimes there are different assemblies within a package for their respective environments.  A .Net 4.0, 4.5, SL assembly, etc.

The build server seems to dump all of the libraries required into a single folder, then pulls from that to build the solution.  This causes problems in many cases, with the wrong project getting the wrong assembly version.  This does not occur locally, only on the build server.  I can't figure out what I need to do to keep this from happening.  Any ideas?

Comment: What version of TFS? This is relevant because in TFS2013, you can configure builds to split multiple solutions apart into multiple folders. Then all you'd have to do is create two solutions, one for each site, and build both solutions as part of the same build.

Also, your ASP .NET projects should automatically get pushed to the "_PublishedWebsites" folder in your build drop, after they run through the ASP .NET compiler. That would also take care of your problem.

Comment: I hope you realize that you are replying to someone else? I was the one who posted the answer you are seeing ;). Also, you should change yout 'tfs' tag for 'tfs2010' since this has very clear differences in the ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks, moved them and retagged :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I hate this standard behavior, but TFS will output everything to the same folder by default, and then you will get various errors depending on which order msbuild compiles your projects if you have references with the same name or even project outputs with the same name.

The easiest workaround is to use the `AsConfigured` option on the Process tab, '2. Build' -> 'Output location' of the build definition window. This keeps your normal source structure intact, but I think you will lose support for automatically dropped outputs (i.e. you will have to provide a script to do that yourself). If you are only using TFS Build for validation, this is the cleanest approach.

You can also use the `PerProject` setting and split up your projects into two distinct solutions, perhaps suffixed by platform (we've done that numerous times in our company). Then, you specify both solutions to the build process and it will create two separate folders in the output, one for each solution.

This is all assuming you are using TFS 2013. In TFS2012, there is a similar option but it is in '3. Advanced' -> 'Solution Specific Build Outputs'. You will probably have to go this route if you are using TFS2012 or you will need to modify the default workflow yourself to add your own logic.

EDIT:

From your comment to the other poster I see you are using TFS 2010. Well... I think this was absolutely not supported at that time, I remember having similar problems, but we upgraded to TFS 2012 and all was well.

I think your only option is to either create two separate build definitions and build each solution that way, or you will need to checkout the xaml workflow and edit it with your own logic. Perhaps downloading the TFS2012 template and "porting" it to TFS2010 would be a better approach since at least you would not be reinventing the wheel that way.

Comment: Sadly, this is for TFS 2010. The AsConfigured approach may be viable though, I'd have to do a bit of scripting to get what I want, but that's preferable to a picky build server.

Comment: Actually, I don't see any of these options in TFS 2010.

Comment: Worth noting, I tried the separate solutions route, ran into problems with Nuget packages improperly restoring for one of the two projects.  Refreshing Nuget from one package made that one work, only to break the other.  Consensus seems to be it's time to upgrade.

Comment: If you can elaborate this new problem (perhaps in a new question) I am certain we can make it work. Our own solutions are very messy here and I managed to make nuget package restore work even with projects referenced in multiple solutions (which I don't think you need in this case). Of course, this is all assuming you cannot upgrade TFS easily, or else I strongly recommend TFS 2013 since the new features are very good.

Comment: As a followup, we moved to TFS 2013 this week, and the `AsConfigured` property did the trick, the normal solution structure was retained.  I then used the information on this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376353.aspx#scripts (and the Powershell script it mentions) to create a post-build step that drops what I want into the bin folder, which is then copied to the drop location.